# loading jquery in cfdiv

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

im using a cfdiv to bind data from another page eg: (bind.cfm?id=123) and that other page(bind.cfm) has a jquery scrollable from flowplayer http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html and its not working it doesnt scroll... i included all the js and css files in that file and nothing, but when i browse to that file directly (bind.cfm?id=123) its fine...

any way to get jquery to work in a cfdiv bind method??

i can explain better if necessary.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the jquery javascript files from the calling page, rather than the bound page (bind.cfm in your example).

Additionally, if you are comfortable using jquery for ajax there's probably not much point using the cfajax tags, as this means you are using ExtJs to load a page that uses JQuery to do stuff. You may experience collisions between the two libraries and your users are downloading two javascript frameworks instead of one.

Comment: i originally did thats by adding the js to the caller and nothing doing... i didn't understand what you meant by Additionally

Comment: @loo, it means that CF uses 3rd-party JS libraries for AJAX (say, ExtJs) and using both your jQuery and these can be not so efficient. So Anthony proposes to do all AJAX stuff with your jQuery instance only.